# Parseval's relation

Tags: probability-theory, parsevals-identity

I've been reading Gut's book for probability theory class. I got stuck on the problem 12 from Chapter 10. (p.198)

I don't know how can I proof via Parseval's relation that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(t)}{\pi t^2}\exp{-|t|}dt=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\ln(2)}{\pi}$$

Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried expanding $(1-\cos(t))/t^2$ in a Taylor series?

Comment: Maybe the book explains that, but the rest of mankind (most of them not having it handy)  might appreciate an explanation why one would prove such a thing at all, and why using Parseval's relation (aka "context").